# GOlang XML parsing / unmarshal

Tags: xml, go

I'm having trouble parsing xml in Go. Can anyone help? The XML format is:

```
<Feed version='1.03' format='FULL' date='2016-04-22T18:31:01.4988282+01:00'>

    <Ids>
            <Id code='000001' quantity='4' />
            <Id code='000002' quantity='0' />
     </Ids>

</Feed>
```

Comment: What do you want to parse out of it? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Check out the [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) package to get started.

Comment: ive just managed to work it out. i was missing the "attr" to pick up the attributes of the Id.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, here's a sample that will roundtrip the mentioned XML to go structs and back:

```
func TestXml(t *testing.T) {
    type Id struct {
        Code string `xml:"code,attr"`
        Quantity int `xml:"quantity,attr"`
    }

    type Feed struct {
        Version string `xml:"version,attr"`
        Format string `xml:"format,attr"`
        Date string `xml:"date,attr"`
        Ids []Id `xml:"Ids>Id"`
    }

    x := []byte(`
        <Feed version='1.03' format='FULL' date='2016-04-22T18:31:01.4988282+01:00'>
            <Ids>
                <Id code='000001' quantity='4' />
                <Id code='000002' quantity='0' />
            </Ids>
        </Feed>
    `)

    f := Feed{}
    xml.Unmarshal(x, &f)
    t.Logf("%#v", f)
    t.Log("Code 0:", f.Ids[0].Code)

    b, _ := xml.Marshal(f)
    t.Log(string(b))
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
xml_test.go:42: domain.Feed{Version:"1.03", Format:"FULL", Date:"2016-04-22T18:31:01.4988282+01:00", Ids:[]domain.Id{domain.Id{Code:"000001", Quantity:4}, domain.Id{Code:"000002", Quantity:0}}}
xml_test.go:43: Code 0: 000001
xml_test.go:46: <Feed version="1.03" format="FULL" date="2016-04-22T18:31:01.4988282+01:00"><Ids><Id code="000001" quantity="4"></Id><Id code="000002" quantity="0"></Id></Ids></Feed>
```

The documentation for [`xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/) contains great examples.